# C++ Linking and COM Registration issue

Tags: c++, windows, com, linker

I've added a new library to my application (multiple projects-DLLs) - SQLite, to perform some in memory caching. There is just one library/project that is affected by this change - Lib1.

A build goes through fine. All libraries are built successfully and no errors are reported, including a couple of Com Objects.

If I try to register the com objects, I get the The *DLL could not be loaded. Check to make sure all required application runtime files and other dependent DLLs are available in the component DLL's directory or the system path.* message. But all the libs are at the same place. And all are in the path. A copy of this project builds and registers fine (without the few changes made for SqlLite ofcourse). Dependency walker reports no issues

Oddly, if I try to register the DLL of the com object (using regsvr32) it works fine. Also, I have another library, which is dependant on Lib1 (not on SqlLite) which also cannot be loaded.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
A'z

Comment: What OS are you running and what program are you using to code?

Comment: Windows XP, and the enviroment is (drumroll) VS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Process Monitor (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) set to filter process name regsvr32.exe in order to see all file and registry access.

Always use full path to your-com-dll when you issue regsvr32 commands, if you have the same dll somewhere else in path (for example c:\windows\system32) regsvr32 will use the other dll and not the one in your current directory.

Another trick would be to use "rundll32 your-com-dll,DllRegisterServer". In case of missing dlls it will tell which dll is missing instead of just saying that LoadLibrary failed.

**Edit**:
What do you mean by "If I try to register the com objects"? How are you doing this? I'm asking because you say that regsvr32 on the dll which actually implements these com object works fine.

Comment: Thanks, will try process monitor tomorrow, and post the results!

Comment: Ok, ran the Process Monitor both for the failing config and the successful config. no difference!
As I mentioned in the first post - regsvr32 completes without error.

Answer (score 0):

Use the dependency walker tool to figure out what other dlls the COM server relies on. Then check the executable paths that is set in Visual Studio (Tools -> Options -> Projects -> Directories (I think)). Note that VS does not use the system PATH environment variable - it uses what is set in the options page so if the path to the dependencies is not listed there, the registration would fail, even though if you used `regsvr32` from the command line it would succeed.

Comment: in question Neil has mentioned that dependency walker didnt report any errors

Comment: The question wasn't by Neil, and I didn't expect it to report any issues. You can use dependency walker to figure out the correct paths to the dependencies

Comment: Thanks,
All libraries I use are in the same folder, in the end. And that folder is the first one in the path.
As I mentioned, I have two copies of the same project. One without the code changes works just fine. And most annoying is the fact that the only lib that actually has changes - loads.

Maybe it helps but - GetLastError returns 126.
a'z

Answer (score 0):

And so, the plot thickens!!!!

I've actually **narrowed down the to the line of code** that causes this linking problem.
In the modified library (LIB1) I've added a new class A1 which inherits from an existing class A.
When I change an existing class B which used to inherit from A to now inherit from A1 - this is when the problem is caused. Class B is in a lib3.

I've verified that just **when I change the inheritance, only then the problem occurs!!!**

I've used file-mon on regsvr32 when loading successfully and when failing. I stuggle to find the difference! Tomorrow morning I'll try Process Monitor and see if it helps.

Still desperate for help,
A'z

Answer (score 0):

hmm... as Christian asks, how else are you attempting to register the objects if regsvr32.exe succeeds?

the rundll32.exe advice is also good. have you tried stepping through DllRegisterServer in a debugger to see precisely when it's failing? this sounds like a potential runtime failure if depends.exe isn't revealing anything.

btw, when i google for that exact error text i see: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldataaccess/thread/402c1767-cf1d-42f0-aec9-e0169dbf1083/, but I assume you've probably already done this search and found it not helpful :)

Comment: Hi,
I can't unswer why regsvr32 works whilst doing it from the ComObject registration window doesn't. The more I debugged the M.S code the less I understand what is causing this failure. 
Read the link thoroughly, tho it didn't help.
Thanks!